# Is Faraday's law applicable exclusively to free charge carriers?

Tags: electromagnetism

Say I had a loop of some material with no free charge carriers. If the loop were kept in a space with a varying magnetic field, would an EMF be generated along the loop? What about a rod of the same material, motionally cutting magnetic feild lines, would an EMF be generated between it's ends?

Comment: An EMF would be produced, a current would not be produced if there are no free charges.